# How to access nested fields in logstash filter step?

Tags: apache2, logstash, filebeat

I'm trying to send my Apache logs down a different pipeline in Logstash. But first  I need to identify them, which I thought the following filter should do:

```
filter {
    if  "apache" in [fileset].[module] {
        tags => ["apache2"]
    }
}
```

But that breaks everything, and I see this (pertinent part only) error:

```
Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [, #, and, or, xor, nand, { at line 20, column 30 (byte 241) after filter {\n    if  \"apache\" in [fileset]",
```

I'm not sure what else to do.

The `fileset.module` isn't a line that's in the log files, obviously - Filebeat is adding it in. But since it's added in, I thought I should be able to read it in Logstash. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind!

First, I installed the mutate plugin in logstash, and now this step works:

```
filter {
    if [fileset][module] == "apache2" {
        mutate {
            add_tag => ["apache2"]
        }
    }
}
```

I saw that you could assign tags during the input process, so i THOUGHT you could add tags further down the pipeline. My bad